# Unable to Render/Return a MongoDB Record by ID in React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

After numerous attempts and minor meltdowns I'm still unable to successfully return an object by its ID in my React frontend. I keep getting the same error of 'Cannot read property 'XXX'' in my Post Component even though the data appears available according to Redux Dev Console and multiple console.logs. I've provided the full Post Component along with all the other relevant code below but here's what I mean....

```
renderPost() {
    console.log(this.props.post);
      //  {  _id: '5d1d93348a966c08c1f4bedb',
      //     title: 'Testing getPost',
      //     user: '5d1129e503da62058a95c481', }

    console.log(this.props.post.title);
      //  ERROR Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <h4 className="title">POST.TITLE HERE</h4>
      </div>
    );}
```

Why can I access and return this.props.post but not something like this.props.post.title? Everything works fine in the backend via PostMan testing so I'm definitely screwing something up here in the front-end, which would mean either the getPost action creator, the GET_POST reducer, or the Post Component.

Honestly I think its somewhere in the reducer or the Post Component but I'm spinning my wheels while simultaneously banging my head against the wall so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

And my apologies if what I provided is either unclear or lacking. I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first time posting here so please excuse any inevitable disasters in decorum.

**getPost Action Creator**

```
export const getPost = _id => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${_id}`);
  dispatch({ type: GET_POST, payload: res.data });
};
```

**getPost Action Payload**

```
{  type: 'GET_POST',
   payload: {
     _id: '5d1d93348a966c08c1f4bedb',
     title: 'Testing getPost',
     user: '5d1129e503da62058a95c481', }}
```

**GET_POST Reducer**

```
import { GET_POSTS, GET_POST } from '../actions/types';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, '_id') };
    case GET_POST:
      return { ...state.post, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
    default:
      return state; }
```

**Resultant Posts State**

```
  {  posts: {
       '5d1d93348a966c08c1f4bedb': {
         _id: '5d1d93348a966c08c1f4bedb',
         title: 'Testing getPost',
         user: '5d1129e503da62058a95c481',
  }}}
```

**POST COMPONENT**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPost } from '../actions';

class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: {}
    };}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPost(this.props.match.params.id);
      // using params._ID instead  results in CastError: 
      // Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'undefined' }" 
      // at path "_id" for model "Posts" }

  renderPost() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <h4 className="title">WANT TO RETURN POST.TITLE HERE</h4>
      </div>
    );}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-top">
        <div>{this.renderPost()}</div>
      </div>
    );}}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { post: state.posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
    // ._id at the end results in post being undefined
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPost })(Post);
```

### **Additional Code**

**MongoDB SCHEMA**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }
  });

const Post = mongoose.model('Posts', postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

**MongoDB FIND BY ID ROUTE**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = mongoose.model('Posts');

  app.get('/api/posts/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const post = await Post.findById({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.json(post);
  });
```

**REDUX REDUCERS**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case GET_POSTS:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, '_id') };

        //  mapKeys is a function in Lodash that takes an array              
        //  and returns an object. Whatever the value of ‘_id’                
        //  is for an object inside an array is now the key for 
        //  that object in a new state object.

    case GET_POST:
      return { ...state.post, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };

        //  Changing to action.payload.ID results in an undefined 
        //  record being created in posts.
        //   { posts: {
        //       undefined: {
        //         _id: '5d1de8e47691dc12cc64b05c',
        //         title: 'xxxxxxxxx',       
        //         user: '5d1129e503da62058a95c481' }}}

    default:
      return state;
  }};
```

**POSTLIST COMPONENT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getPosts } from '../actions';

class PostsList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPosts(); }

  renderPosts() {
    return this.props.posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <div className="content" key={post._id}>
          <h4 className="title">
            <Link className="title" to={`/posts/${post._id}`}>
              {post.title}
            </Link>
          </h4>
        </div>
      );});}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-top">
        <div>{this.renderPosts()}</div>
      </div>
    );}}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    posts: Object.values(state.posts)
  };};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPosts }
)(PostsList);
```

Comment: Its strange. Just a line before it console logs whole object and on next line it is saying of undefined. Try to console this `const {title} = this.props.post; console.log(title)`

Comment: it resulted in another undefined property value unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPost action is asynchronous

can you update Post Component like below and give a try?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPost } from '../actions';

class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      post: {}
    };}

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getPost(this.props.match.params.id);
    await this.setState({loaded: true}); 
  }

  renderPost() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <h4 className="title">{this.props.post.title}</h4>
      </div>
    );}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-top">
        <div>{this.state.loaded && this.renderPost()}</div>
      </div>
    );}}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { post: state.posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
    // ._id at the end results in post being undefined
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPost })(Post);
```

Comment: Yippee-Ki-Yay it worked! Thank you so much for the help. This was driving me crazy. You've saved my sanity and my blood pressure. Have a great 4th of July.